# Show all columns in MySQL tables without null values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database of historical personas with the following three tables:

```
t_name
t_occupation
t_location
```

t_name includes all the bio-infos, e.g. name, surname, dateofbirth, etc. 
t_occupation lists possible occupations (writer, singer, etc.) and is the foreign key to the t_name column "id_occupation"
t_location lists all the locations with plz and links as foreign key to a couple of columns in t_name table, e.g. id_birthplace, id_placeofdeath, id_placeofliving, etc.

I'd like to generate an output of the whole database which lists all historical personas with all the columns that are not null (so for example, Persona 1 may have an id_birthplace but id_placeofdeath is unknown, so id_placeofdeath should not be listed, but the rest should).

In PHP 4.0, I used variables to store the info and worked with if-statements to generate the list (mysql_result), but this is no longer possible with PHP 7.0.

How do I do this in the latest version?

I tried the following code:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t_name AS table, IF(COUNT(name), NOT NULL, name) AS column
                                     FROM t_name
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT t_location AS table, IF(COUNT(location), NOT NULL, location) AS column FROM t_ort
                                     UNION ALL)
                                     WHERE column IS NULL");



  while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
      echo $dsatz["name"] . ", "
          .$satz["location"] . "<br /> <br />";
    }
```

The only result I get is: records found but no listing. What did I get wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is about... right now I just assume you're looking for something that you can use instead of mysql_result, since this function has been removed with php7. It my assumption is right, you should have a look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php there are some alternative listed, I'd recommend PDO

Comment: What does "plz" mean in the context of "all the locations with plz and links"?

Comment: PLZ = Postal Code
it links as foreign key to a couple of columns in t_name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT tableA AS table, IF(COUNT(column_a), NOT NULL, column_a) AS column 
FROM tableA 
UNION ALL 
SELECT tableB AS table, IF(COUNT(column_b), NOT NULL, column_b) AS column FROM tableB 
UNION ALL -- etc. ) t 
WHERE column IS NULL
```